What does "rintro rfl" do in LEAN?
Here is a block of LEAN code:
import Mathlib.Data.Real.Basic

example {x y : ℝ} (h : x ≤ y) : ¬y ≤ x ↔ x ≠ y := by
  constructor
  · contrapose!
    rintro rfl
    rfl
  contrapose!
  exact le_antisymm h

Why does LEAN change every "y" instance in both the premise and the conclusion to "x" after writing "rintro rfl"?

Please add the imports needed.

Added. There are some locally defined libraries too, but I believe they are not relevant here.

rintro combines intros and rcases.
Also, note that equality is an inductive type with one constructor:
Eq.refl : ∀ {α : Sort u_1} (a : α), a = a

This means we can use induction or cases on an equality, not too differently from how we use it on a natural number.  In this setting the induction principle says if we have x = y and our goal is true with all ys replaced with x, then it is true as is.  This is called "path induction".
example {x y : ℝ} (h : x ≤ y) : ¬y ≤ x ↔ x ≠ y := by
  constructor
  · contrapose!
    intros h1
    cases h1  -- or `induction h1` or `rcases h1`
    /-
    x : ℝ
    h : x ≤ x
    ⊢ x ≤ x
    -/
    rfl
  contrapose!
  exact le_antisymm h

Now, rcases (and hence rintro) has a very complicated and advanced interface filled with a lot of symbolic shorthand for special cases.  It looks like  here rfl is just a special keyword for rcases for this setting of matching on an equality.  (See the docs for rcases in Lean 3.)  So it is neither referring to the tactic rfl nor the theorem rfl.
